# Is there a JavaFX Label only returning the last row

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, label, resultset

in my code there is an executestatement which works perfectly with System.out.println but when i want to get out with label1.setText(rs.getString(1) + ", " + rs.getString(2)
1 is the user name,  2 is the user departure date

So here is the code:

```
try {
      String SQL = "SELECT * FROM `tagok` WHERE tagok.vegdatum = CURDATE() ORDER BY tagID DESC LIMIT 5;";
      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      boolean results = stmt.execute(SQL);
      int rsCount = 0;

      //Loop through the available result sets.
     do {
        if(results) {
           ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
           rsCount++;

           //Show data from the result set.
           System.out.println("RESULT SET #" + rsCount);
           while (rs.next()) {
              System.out.println(rs.getString(2) + ", " + rs.getString(3));
              taglejar.setText( rs.getString("tagszam") + ", " + rs.getString("vegdatum") + "\r\n" );
           }
           rs.close();
        }
        System.out.println();
        results = stmt.getMoreResults();
        } while(results);
      stmt.close();
      }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

So my output with System out print: RESULT SET #1
Név:aaaaaaaaaa, 2019-04-01
adfadfafd, 2019-04-18
sdfafd, 2019-04-18

And my FXML Label only return the last row: sdfafd, 2019-04-18 and i would like to return all the elements.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: "And my FXML Label only return the last row" - you keep overwriting the text in the label by `taglejar.setText( rs.getString("tagszam") + ", " + rs.getString("vegdatum") + "\r\n" )` .For testing purposes try `taglejar.setText(taglejar.getText()+ rs.getString("tagszam") + ", " + rs.getString("vegdatum") + "\r\n" )`. For implementation use `TableView`,  `ListView` , or `TextArea`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, yes i completely forget that i overwrite with that... now its working and yes i already changed to TextArea!